# How to delete all full-black images in a folder?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

After cropping and saving images, I found that there are many full black images (RGB = 0,0,0). I want to delete these images.

The followings are the codes I have tried:

```
import os, glob
from PIL import image

def CleanUp_images():
    for filename in glob.glob('/Users/Xin/Desktop/TestFolder/*.jpg'):
        im = Image.open(filename)
        pix = list(im.getdata())
        if pix == [(0,0,0)]:
            os.remove(im)

CleanUp_images()
```

However, the above codes didn't work out
Can anyone give me a help?

Comment: You need to give much more specific details about "didn't work out".  That could mean almost anything from "the computer crashed when I ran it", to "it deleted all the full-black images as expected, except for one of them".

Comment: `os.remove(filename)` will work since it's the filename, not the image object

Answer (score -1):

With `os.remove(im)` you're passing an image object to `os.remove` which only accepts strings when you just have to do:

```
os.remove(filename)
```

`filename` is the absolute path to your file (thanks to `glob`), so it will work.

Also `if pix == [(0,0,0)]:` this isn't going to work because the list has more than 1 element, even if all elements are black pixels. What works is creating a set of rgb tuples. If there are only black pixels the set has a size of 1:

```
if set(pix) == {(0,0,0)}:
```